# waking up from locked screen with just keyboard

Tags: macos, screen-lock

I'm on OS X 10.9.5. I do not like using mouse/trackpad, and mostly work with keyboard only. One annoying thing is that when the OS is locked (screen lock) and the power saving for the monitor is activated, I can't wake it up with a keystroke. I MUST move the mouse cursor to let me type in my password to unlock the screen.

Does anybody else have the same problem and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Is your keyboard connected over USB or Bluetooth?

Comment: @grgarside USB keyboard (HHK light)

Comment: Space Bar wakes mine up. Mouse used to, before 10.9 but no longer.

Comment: I have a worse problem on Yosemite… I have to *click* to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

On 10.9.5 You could use the Accessibility option and enable mouse keys  if you have a keyboard number pad.

There are some optional settings there to choose from like:

By clicking 5 times on the Option key you can turn that feature on or off.